# @gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I've been using the library to create bottom sheet modals for my react native app, but it's doesn't seem to work on Android, but on iOS it does. I used the same backdrop component and handle component suggested in the docs, and everything is contained is the provider, and SafeAreaView
my package.json includes

```
"@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^3.6.5", 
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0",
```

and the code is structured like this:

```
     <BottomSheetModal ref={reference_settings}
                            index      = {1}
                            enableOverDrag={true}
                            onChange   = {(index) => { if(index === 0) { reference_settings.current.dismiss(); } }}
                            snapPoints = {[-1, '50%', '70%']}
                            backdropComponent={Backdrop}
                            handleComponent  ={(props) => (<Belt {...props} />)}
                            style            ={styles.sheet}
                        >
                        <BottomSheetView style={[styles.content]}>
                            <View style={{ width, height: '100%', overflow: 'hidden', backgroundColor: scheme === 'dark' ? '#000' : '#FFF', paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
                              // the functions inside
                            </View>
                       </BottomSheetView>
</BottomSheetModal>
```

I used the right configuration for babel for react-native-reanimated including the plugin, but it shows up and then I can't drag to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's a bit late to answer for you but I would like to add for others. Assuming you already installed `react-native-gesture-handler` you should also add some lines of code to your MainActivity.java.

[image]

Comment: This gives `Build Failed: MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API` for me

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to wrap your Root App Component like this in the index.js file

place the the import statement at the top of index.js

```
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));
```

[more details](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/installation#:%7E:text=After%20installation%2C%20wrap%20your%20entry%20point%20with%20%3CGestureHandlerRootView%3E%20or%20gestureHandlerRootHOC.)